# How to use Azure CLI "az acr" command with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to create custom `Azure DevOps Server 2019` task. For Windows I already created `.ps1` script but I'm having trouble with Linux - for that I chose to write in `TypeScript` as I really do not like writing in `js`. Script is as simple as it gets

```
let registry = "Registry3";//argv[1]
let timestamp = "2020-01-01";//argv[2]
let repository = "hello-world";//to be looped

az acr repository show-manifests --name registry --repository repository --orderby time_asc -o tsv;
```

Trying to compile that with `tsc file.ts` gives following error

```
Clean-ACR.ts:54:6 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

54   az acr repository show-manifests --name registry --repository repository --orderby time_asc -o tsv;
        ~~~
```

And so on for every single word from "acr" until end of line. Obviously TypeScript doesn't handle this line as it has incorrect syntax. But how am I supposed to use this command? I'm complete newby with TypeScript so pardon my incompetence

Answer (score 0):

Try using template strings, like this:

```
`az acr ${repository} show-manifests --name ${registry} --repository ${repository} --orderby time_asc -o tsv`
```

Answer (score 0):

You look like you're trying to run shell commands, so you might be in a better position to use bash scripts.

However, if you want to use TypeScript with node you will need [ts-node](https://www.github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) and the [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) APIs in node.

Here's an example using JavaScript (so no need for ts-node) but with TypeScript type checking: [orta/make-monaco-builds/publish-monaco-ts.js](https://github.com/orta/make-monaco-builds/blob/49932ab7f3188c12d4ce753b084d038e951b04df/publish-monaco-ts.js)